# GMSGeometryLength in Android

Tags: android, ios, path, location, distance

I am porting a iOS code on Android, and I need to get the length of a polyline, which I have as an Array of LatLng's.

This is the code of the IOS app that I'm trying to replicate:

```
     GMSPath *pathOfStep = nextDict[@"path"];
                double progressOnStep = GMSGeometryLength(pathOfStep);
```

Now how could I get the same length on android?
I could do a for that goes through the list of LatLng's and create Location for each one of them and calculate the distance from each one to the next adding them. But I am looking for a more optimised option.
Any ideeas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `Google Maps Android API utility library`.
The library has a class `SphericalUtil` which provides the static method

```
public static double computeLength(List<LatLng> path);
```

The library holds several other convenient methods for computing area, heading and other things as well.

Simply add the library as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file and you are set to go.

F.ex.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'   
}
```

The project is on Github

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Comment: Thanks a lot, will test now to see if I manage to do it and will complete answer after